# MS Access print preview in word is missing images

Tags: ms-access, migration, ms-access-2007

We recently upgraded from Access 2000 to 2007, and it broke an aspect of the reports preview.  Now when we click to preview as .RTF in MS Word, the images are missing.

I fully expect to get the Tumbleweed badge for this question, but I'd rather get an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it may not be an answer to you explicit question but in 2007 there is PDF format available which will give you a much nicer and more flexible output format.

Comment: thanks, but actually the issue was that the users of the system wanted the ability to edit the "report" (actually a form letter) before it went out.